# Force Java Awt to crash fully when hitting exception

Tags: java, exception, awt

debugging my java awt gui app here. Exceptions are thrown in my drawing methods. But awt keeps on going. Which can be annoying for debugging purposes. Is there a way to tell awt that I want the application to crash entirely when hitting an exception?

Comment: `System.exit(1);` Zero is for normal termination, an uncaught exception probably isn't normal.

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to achieve that by setting ui thread exception handler that will exit application.
Check Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler.
I never tried it myself though.